# Dealing with expert opinions

Tags: evidence, rules-of-court, rules-of-evidence, civil-legal-system

> Every Economist who is consistent with their discipline subscribes to
> the subjective theory of value; **how does a Judge who wants to be
> consistent with Economics and coincidentally also is a B.A in
> economics deal with an Expert Report that treats Value as Objective?**
>
> Law frequently deals with value (the value of something; at what price
> it would be bought or sold) but seems to take lightly the
> philosophical depth of the concept of Value. It seems that a judge
> should accept the expert opinion as is and can't consider its
> methodology or philosophy. We just let the expert tell us what value
> is without any thought. It is what it is.

Above was the previous phrasing of the question. A more general phrasing would be

**How can a judge deal with methodological flaws in expert opinions?**

The above is an example when the expert says the Value of X item is Y but it can't actually be bought or sold at that price. The Judge may have personal expertise in the field of the expert opinion or it can be common knowledge. Do we just say expert opinions are what they are and we must accept at face value the least fallacious?

I am asking in the Context of how courts in Civil Law system appoint Experts.

Comment: Which jurisdiction are we talking? In some jurisdictions, judges can't determine the value of things but rely on a court-appointed expert, in others they have to assume the listed value of things, in others they have prescribed formulas - this all depends on the rules of  the court.

Comment: @Trish It is a question precisely on Jurisprudence/Philosophy of Law. It is not about some specific jurisdiction (but since I was taking about expert opinions It is safe to assume that the question was talking about the jurisdiction that have their judges "rely" on court-appointment experts). It is about the treatment of concepts outside of the Law (in particular Value).

Comment: Jurisprudence in **which legal system**? What is good in *one* system is not in another. Just look at the difference between how the value of a stolen good is determined in Germany (market value of a similar product) from the Code of Hammurabi, where the value of a stolen item is irrelevant: [Temple Thieves, abductors and robbers are executed, the city compensates lost items if the robber escapes](http://www.wright.edu/~christopher.oldstone-moore/Hamm.htm)

Comment: @Trish Is the Philosophy (something Metaphysical/not Empirical) system dependent? If I was pressured on stating a system in mind I would state the German or French systems. But I believe that philosophy is invariant so that is why I believe it was not important. Because it is not about what a French or a German judge does but about the treatment in law of the philosophical issue of value.

Comment: @Trish Ι don't understand how the question is not clear.

Comment: You need to tell us something about the legal system, you ask about. Jurisprudence does not exist in a vacuum! The LEgal Theory behind the Code of Hammurabi is vastly different from the one behind Roman Law which is different from Justinian Law which is different form Code Civil and Common Law. Are you asking for a Natural Law analysis? Or Virtue Jurisprudence?

Comment: @Trish I earnestly don't follow you. The Legal Theory of Command Theory of law and Pure Theory of law are vastly different too. But these are irrelevant. Command Theory of Law and Pure (Normative) Theory of Law are invariant (yes they do exist indepenently of a specific legal system they are the same in China, Africa, America or Europe). I am not asking about a specific legal system. The answer should be invariant (considering that European and American legal systems ( tell the judge to) treat expert opinions in the same way).

Comment: You are wrong: in a German court, you can't just *bring an expert*, the court decides when and which court-appointed expert evaluates the value during a trial, using the reasoning that that expert needs to be truly independent and only obliged to the court. I get the feeling you want to ask about *common law experts*. These are not even free to come up with numbers from thin air, they have to follow strict guidelines and can't divert from that. Your question simply *doesn't work* under the German Prozessordnung.

Comment: @Trish I didn't understand this difference. When I was told that a judge appoints an expert in America it was the same thing as not being able to just bring an expect. I had a prejudice of domestic law (I have 3 nationalities Greek-Brazilian-Italian and I understood that everywhere was the same). I was prejudiced by the Civil Law System and thought that a judge appointing an expect had the same meaning in Common Law.

Comment: @Trish I wanted to ask about Civl Law (legal system and thought that Common Law experts followed the same rules). Δικονομικό Δίκαιο, Direito Processual, Diritto Processuale.

Comment: Ahhh, there's the problem: In Code Civil areas, the court decides to either believe the party's bills or values, uses preset formulas to evaluate from new-value or do appoint an expert to tell them the value of items. in common law, Courts **can't** appoint experts. In common law, the **parties** each bring their experts and the jury decides which one is correct, they are the trier of facts. The Judge only decides which law applies. On a Bench trial, the Judge also is the Jury.

Comment: @Trish This comment should have told you that it was about Civil Law legal systems. https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/77263/dealing-with-expert-opinions#comment163471_77263

Comment: You should have tagged it as such back then. I told you before that several times, that different systems use different reasoning to come to their court rules and processes - which are **vastly** different. The philosophy behind Code Hamurabi is much different than behind Code Civil which is different from Common Law.

Comment: @Trish A judge appoints an expert and their report is scientifically/tecnically wrong (the say the value of X is Y when it can't be bought or sold for Y not because they simply got a number wrong and they did mathematics/statistics/measurement wrong but because their methodology was wrong) the judge understands this. What can they do? How does Legal Theory deal with that (an expert who does not know his job and what value actually is).

Comment: @Trish If the judge hasn't been trained in Economics they will simply accept whatever the expert they appointed says (it takes and Economist or at least someone with some expertise or experience to question if the item X could actually be sold at price Y). In the list of the experts the ones who do the evaluations are not economists. It just does not sit right.

Comment: @Trish Neither the expert knows what value actually is (what does it really mean for item X to have a value of Y) nor Law (Civil Law) seems to care about such philosophical, theoretical, issues. Law says "Value is whatever our experts said" and doesn't care if the expert themselves actually know what it is.

Comment: The Blackletter Law and precedent will tell the judge what they have to do then. Which is why **Jurisdiction matters** in this case.

Comment: @Trish we are talking about Civil Law legal systems not Common Law

Answer (score 2):

The law does not deal with a judge who wants to be consistent with Economics and coincidentally also is a B.A in economics. The law just deals with judges, irrespective of their desires. The law simply tells the judge "Follow the law" – what constitutes following the law differs from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. This is so whether the issue is statutory interpretation or the determination of loss in a contract dispute, or some issue touching on the notion of "profound injustice".

In the US, [this](https://www.law.cornell.edu/rules/fre/rule_702) is the basic rule regarding admissibility of expert testimony. It starts:

> A witness who is qualified as an expert by knowledge, skill,
> experience, training, or education may testify in the form of an
> opinion or otherwise if

Then the court must decide whether a particular witness satisfies the conditions. The criteria are that the specialized knowledge will help the trier of fact, and is based on sufficient facts, and appropriate to your question

> (c) the testimony is the product of reliable principles and methods;
> and
>
> (d) the expert has reliably applied the principles and methods to the
> facts of the case.

Note that the sociology of a method is not an explicit component of this rule. In fact, voiceprint evidence is still admissible in many US jurisdictions although it has been thoroughly rejected in the scientific community. Evidence that is admitted which goes against the interests of one party is stiff defeasible under US law.

If a witness is to testify solely to a self-evident fact that is not disputed, the witness' testimony is irrelevant because it does not help the trier of fact.

Comment: Let's say that some statute says award the value,(i.e award the amount of money that something (that thing) would be bought or sold). Any statute that would require the judge to find out the value of something does the job it was just an example. The Judge appoints an expert and the expert report has mistakes in both methodology and philosophy (it doesn't follow the lex artis of Economics). Can the Judge examine the methodology and the philosophy of the expert report (whether it followed lex artis) or can he only examine the honesty of the expert alone and accept the expert report in toto?

Comment: Do you want more details on expert testimony under US law? Judges don't appoint experts, they rule on the admissibility of expert testimony.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulous which is where the legal school and jurisdiction come in: what is gob of a judge and what they may not do is jurisdiction based.

Comment: @user6726 Is the admissibility all or nothing? Can they only either accept the expert report in its totality or dismiss it in its totality? What happens when the expert is honest but their methodology is faulty or when they have fallacies? Can the judge check it too?

Comment: Ι don't understand how the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1):

### The judge considers the evidence presented and the law

**Any judge that brings in evidence that neither party has contended is in error.**

In common law jurisdictions, the purpose of a lawsuit is to resolve the dispute between the parties using the evidence that the parties submit: the judge is not there to introduce things the parties don't submit.

If the parties agree that value is objective or that pigs can fly, then the court accepts that, for this case, those things are facts. If there is a dispute on these facts, then each side presents evidence that supports their position and on the evidence and only on the evidence, the judge decides which party has proved their position - a judge should not substitute personal knowledge for evidence.

Similarly, just because the current paradigm among economists is that value is relative or the paradigm among chemists is that fire is hot is irrelevant. Each side can introduce evidence (probably expert evidence) on the relativeness of value or the hotness of fire and where those experts disagree (as they invariably do), the judge decides whose evidence they prefer.

That does not mean that a judge who is an expert in another field cannot utilise their expertise but that should be constrained to asking the parties to bring evidence. For example: "You guys are arguing on the basis the value is objective but you haven't submitted any evidence that the court should accept that premise, rather than the alternative that it's relative. Can you make submissions on this matter or agree that for this case you want the court to treat value as objective?"

Comment: If there is a dispute that there was a Presidential Election in 2020 or on the current day (what date is today) can the judge only decide on the evidence? Can they substitute common knowledge, rules of physics/rules of nature, common sense?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Yes. No. If the parties are disputing the fact that there was an election then that is a matter that must be decided on the evidence. If the parties **agree** that there wasn’t one, then the case proceeds with that as an established fact. Common law courts are not interested in capital T truth - that’s for philosophy, not law - they only exist to resolve the dispute.

Comment: And let's say there really is dispute (there is no agreement that there wasn't an election on 2020) but the party with the stronger evidence is actually false (the Judge knows it because these are the rules of nature, common knowledge). Are they still forbidden from using it? Civil Procedure is about the formal (not substantial/not in content) truth so if the parties agree we are fine (whatever they agree to is a fact) but when there is dispute there seems to be space for common knowledge and rules of nature to be evidence.

Comment: Most jurisdictions uphold that only facts are subject to evidence and iura novit curia (the Court knows the Law and that is not a matter of evidence/matter of fact any opinions may only persuade the court and they are not evidence) and have Common Knowledge and Rules of Nature in their Rules of Evidence. These same jurisdictions (that allow for Rules of Nature and Common Knowledge to be Evidence even if no one adduces them) seem to expect the Court to appoint an Expert and accept whatever they say as long as they are honest even if they make blatant mistakes in the methodology of their Report.

Comment: Ι don't understand how the question is not clear.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos the question is clear. So is the answer.